# How to open a file using text read from a file in c

Tags: c, file-io

I have a file which contains the files names for every file in a directory. I am trying to open that file, read the file names from it and then open each file. However, I cannot get it to open the files. I have it printing the word it is reading and know it is reading correctly; however, it will not open the file. Any suggestions? My program is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

FILE *in;
FILE *in2;
char inName[] = "inputfile.txt";
char *inName2;
inName2 = malloc(36 * sizeof (char));
char inPhrase[100]; 

if (( in = fopen(inName, "r")) == NULL ) 
{
    printf("Can't open %s for reading.\n", inName);
    return 2;
}

else 
{
    fgets(inName2, 36, in);
}

if (( in = fopen(inName2, "r")) == NULL )
{
    printf("Can't open %s for reading. \n", inName2);
}

else
{
    fgets(inPhrase, 100, in2);
    printf("%s\n", inPhrase);
}

fclose(in);
fclose(in2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not opening the file? Did you get an error? Is the path in the file correct?

Comment: Yes, it prints the error message and then exits.

Comment: Well, what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: The one that I have programmed in if it does not open.

Comment: Either free `inName2` or allocate on the stack using `...[36]` notation.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the path. What would be the proper way to open the file using the variable and specify the path? The file is located in a subdirectory to the current location called "DataFiles".

Comment: It has to do with `fgets` reading in a newline in addition to the crap you want and the OP not displaying error messages. I have provided an answer but am still voting to close this question unless the OP posts the output.

Answer (score 2):

You have one outright typo and one mistake in your code. The line `if (( in = fopen(inName2, "r")) == NULL )` should open `in2` instead: `if (( in2 = fopen(inName2, "r")) == NULL )`. Your error message almost certainly reads something like this:

```
Can't open test_file.txt
for reading
```

Notice the newline that `fgets` always reads in for you. You should trim the line somehow. There are a few options available:

1. If your last line is guaranteed to be newline terminated, you can just remove the last character from each line: `strchr(inName2, '\0')[-1] = '\0';`.
2. You can trim the whitespace from the end of each line.
3. You can delete the last character only if it is `\n` (or possibly two characters, `\r\n` on Windows)

Final note: you should always post your error messages. If you were clever enough to interpret it properly in the first place, you would not be posting here, so don't expect us to take your word for where the program failed.

Comment: I have edited the file to remove the new line from the end of the array; however, I am not getting a new error message. it is: Can't open test1.txtB0 for reading. Segmentation fault (Core Dumped). Where is the B0 coming from? I cannot remove it from the end of the array. If I remove another character it deletes the t and leaves the B0.

Comment: You have to make sure your array is NUL terminated. That is how most C functions know where strings end. When you say "removed" what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char inName[] = "inputfile.txt", * inName2;
    FILE * in = fopen(inName, "r"), * in2;
    char inPhrase[100];
    size_t len;

    // Check whether file opened correctly or display error
    if (in == NULL) { perror(inName); return 1; }

    // Read file line by line
    while (getline(&inName2, &len, in) != -1) {
        // Check if file opens otherwise go to next file
        if ((in2 = fopen(inName2, "r")) == NULL) { perror(inName2); continue; }
        // Read 100 chars from each file and display
        fgets(inPhrase, 100, in2);
        printf("%s\n", inPhrase);
        fclose(in2);
    }

    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```